# How to pass the Jtable data in to one frame to another in java netbeans

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtable

i am creating a simple inventory sale system. everything working fine but i want to send the jtable data into to print frame.i can only send total value to print frame. Jtable data how to sent.

**Sales System Screen shot**
[image]

**Jtable code**

```
 DefaultTableModel dtm;
    dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    dtm.addRow(new Object[]
    { 
        txtproduct.getText(),
        txtprice.getText(),

    });
```

this way i added data in to the JTable i need to pass the data to print frame. 
**i tried this way**
    new print(total,jTable1.getModel()).setVisible(true);
**but it diplayed error no suitable constractor found**

**Print Recipt**
[image]

**Pos.java**

```
String total = txttotal.getText();        
new print(total,jTable1.getModel()).setVisible(true);
```

Print.java

```
String ltotal;
 public print(String name,String age,String total)
{
   initComponents(); 
  this.ltotal = total;
  txtarea.setText(txtarea.getText() +"************************************\n"); 
  txtarea.setText(txtarea.getText() +"**********LOS Super*********\n");
  txtarea.setText(txtarea.getText() +"\n");
  txtarea.setText(txtarea.getText() +"Total............"  + ltotal + "\n");

}
```

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call a constructor like `new print(total,jTable1.getModel())`, then you have to write that constructor like this:

(I think you get the error because your program does not have this constructor. If you add this, the error would go away.)

```
public print(String total, TableModel tableModel)
{
  initComponents();
  this.ltotal = total;
  txtarea.setText(txtarea.getText() +"************************************\n");
  txtarea.setText(txtarea.getText() +"**********LOS Super*********\n");
  txtarea.setText(txtarea.getText() +"\n");
  txtarea.setText(txtarea.getText() +"Total............"  + ltotal + "\n");

  txtarea.setText(txtarea.getText() + "Product    Price\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < tableModel.getRowCount(); i++)
  {
    String product = (String) tableModel.getValueAt(i, 0);
    String price = (String) tableModel.getValueAt(i, 1);
    txtarea.setText(txtarea.getText() + product + "    " + price + "\n");
  }
}
```

Another suggestion for improvement:
Instead of calling `txtarea.setText()` many times, you can append the text to a `String` variable and call `setText()` only once at the end.

Comment: new print(total,jTable1.getModel()) getting error but it diplayed error no suitable constractor found

Comment: Yes, so if you add this constructor I've written to `print` class, the error should go away.

Comment: new print(total,jTable1.getModel());  error is displayed  type of the (String,jTable1.getModel()) erroneous.

Comment: Did you add the constructor (`public print(String total, TableModel tableModel)`) given in my solution?

Comment: new print(total,jTable1.getModel()); is now ok no error displayed but when i click print button nothing happing why

Comment: working sir thanks for your help how to print the print form

Comment: Please add print button's action listener code and other relevant code to your question. Without seeing the code, we cannot figure out the problem.

Comment: i simply called txtarea.print() it worked sir. is it ok sir

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can do here if you want to access content of one Jtable from other pane is that you create an array dimensions will be dependent on the type of data for example if there are two columns then there will be two dimensions and so on.

Here you can make the that array static or public that is providing data to the table and access the content from other pane.

Here is the Sample Code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import javax.swing.JScrollPane; 
import javax.swing.JTable; 

public class JTableExamples { 
    // frame 
    JFrame f; 
    // Table 
    JTable j; 

    // Constructor 
    JTableExamples() 
    { 
        // Frame initiallization 
        f = new JFrame(); 

        // Frame Title 
        f.setTitle("JTable Example"); 

        // Data to be displayed in the JTable 
        public String[][] data = { 
            { "Kundan Kumar Jha", "4031", "CSE" }, 
            { "Anand Jha", "6014", "IT" } 
        }; 

        // Column Names 
        String[] columnNames = { "Name", "Roll Number", "Department" }; 

        // Initializing the JTable 
        j = new JTable(data, columnNames); 
        j.setBounds(30, 40, 200, 300); 

        // adding it to JScrollPane 
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(j); 
        f.add(sp); 
        // Frame Size 
        f.setSize(500, 200); 
        // Frame Visible = true 
        f.setVisible(true); 
    } 

    // Driver  method 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        new JTableExamples(); 
    } 
}
```

Now as Here the the Array Data is the Public so you can access it from other scenes.

Comment: can you write the code easy for me to understand sir

Comment: if not sir is there any way to print JTable and jtextfield data sir

Comment: Yes You can print the Jtable Data in PDF or any other document and then print that document.

Comment: Use the Following YouTube Video as a Tutorial for this Purpose
https://youtu.be/yhqu-NG-AzY